# Extracting table contents from a website with expandable table using Python and Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I want to extract the following numbers from this website: https://www.allabolag.se/5560566258/bokslut

I have tried using Selenium and I managed to extract the numbers by row:

```
4 806   1 709   486 
4 025   2 120   435 
526       15    2   
-38       12    2   
-48       7     2
```

But then I realised these are only for 3 latest years (2017, 2016, and 2015).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import re

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/gabriele/Downloads/chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.allabolag.se/5569640369/bokslut")

income_statement_raw = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bokslut")

income_statement_raw_box = income_statement_raw.find_elements_by_class_name("box")

#expected 4806  1709   486  177

year_count_of_financial_data_raw = income_statement_raw_box[0].find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="table__container table__container--padding-bleed-x box__bleed-x--up-to-small"]//table[@class="table--background-separator company-table"]/tbody')

print(year_count_of_financial_data_raw[0].text)

driver.close()
```

I expect to receive 4 numbers since I can see it in the html (see image):[image]

```
2017-12 2016-12 2015-12 2014-12
  4806    1709    486     177



but the result so far is:
2017-12 2016-12 2015-12 
4 806   1 709    486
```

Comment: It seems table data for all previous years is loaded in html, If you want to extract all, i suggest to scrape the site with modules you aware among scrapy, bs4, requests, HTMLParser e.t.c

Comment: I asked another question which is why I am not able to extract all of the tds from the html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used BeautifulSoup to parse the webpage for you.

I am not 100% sure about the data you want to extract so I focused on the "expected data" you showed in your post but in the data variable you will find all the rows contained in the extracted table.

Please remember putting the chromedriver for your platform in the script folder (uncomment the headless row to make the browser invisible).

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://www.allabolag.se/5569640369/bokslut"
options = Options()
#options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
first_table = soup.select_one("table:nth-of-type(1)")

data = []
rows = first_table.find_all('tr')
for row in rows:
    cols = row.find_all('td')
    cols = [ele.text.strip().replace(" ", "") for ele in cols]
    data.append([ele for ele in cols if ele]) 

print(data[1])
#>>> ['4806', '1709', '486', '177']
```

Comment: Oh wow this is great. Thank you! I haven't seen the use of "table:nth-of-type" before. I will look more into it.

Comment: Happy to read that it was useful. It is a simple CSS selector, you can read more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp